# How to pass selected image from UIImagePicker to the UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I've implemented a `UIImagePicker` into my app, but I'm struggling to pass the `UIImage` to the `UIViewController` that the picker was initiated from (see comment in code below)

The below code is an extension stored in **Extensions/ImageUploader.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

extension UIViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{


    public func ImagePicker() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        // mediaType is image only by default

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        }
        if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:{print("Image upload started")})// Closing the window before the upload, so upload can continue in background while user finishes the form

           // Here I want to pass the selectedImageFromPicker to the ViewController that initiated the imagePicker - how do I do that??


        })
        }
}
```

In the **createActivityVC**, I have this IBAction to get access to `photo library` and initiative the picker - self.imagePicker()

```
@IBAction func addPictureBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({(status:PHAuthorizationStatus) in
        switch(status) {

       case .notDetermined:

        // Access has not been determined.
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in

            if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                // Access has been granted.

                self.imagePicker() 
            }

            else {

            }
        })
        break

    case .restricted:
        break

    case .denied:
        // Access has been denied.
        print("Acccess to photo denied")
        break

    case .authorized:
        // Access has been granted.
        print("Access to photo authorized")

         self.imagePicker()

         break


      }
   })
}
```

I want to pass the `selectedImageFromPicker` to viewController **createActivityVC**. How can this be done? I would prefer to not name the viewController specifically but rather make it so that it is dynamic so the imagePicker can be used across multiple ViewControllers if possible.

Comment: Where is this code? If it's in the VC you are presenting the picker (and you've properly made it the picker delegate) all you need to do is make `selectedImageFromPicker` available *outside* of `imagePickerController(didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo)`. And from the looks of things, you've done all this. So either it's a simple matter of variable scope or you haven't said specifically what the issue is.

Comment: Good question. I've updated the question to reflect this. The imagePicker function that is called in the ViewController is actually stored as an extension "imageUploader.swift" so therefore not part of the ViewController file

Comment: Ah, just read your comments on the proposed answer.  You have a few choices available to you. Off the top of my head, make the picker instance - which is just a specific view controller - available to any/all controllers as needed. A second option is to not worry about it... just instantiate the picker where needed. (But yes, this is poor design.) Third, refactor things so that your app doesn't need more than one controller to present the picker - and when you need to pass is, just pass the image (by either presenting the next controller or segueing to it.

Comment: if I can have the imagePicker() return the selectedImageFromPicker then I think it should be solved.... is that possible?

Comment: Have you created your own delegates much? This almost sounds like a good candidate for that. You don't need to "name" the interested view controller - instead you make any interested VC be a delegate of the VC doing the presenting of the picker. At that point the "picker VC" simply tells whatever VC doing the presenting that a new image was selected.

Comment: No I have never done this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, have you implemented a UIImageView? If it's the case, in your

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

you can say:

```
myFormImageView.image = selectedImageFromPicker
```

and then when you submit your form you can upload the form info + the image data

**UPDATE:**

My approach by subclassing UIIMagePickerController

```
import UIKit

protocol ImagePickerDelegate {
    func imagePicked(image: UIImage)
}

class myPickerViewController: UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    var imagePickerDelegate:ImagePickerDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        allowsEditing = true
        delegate = self
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            imagePickerDelegate.imagePicked(image: selectedImage)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class ViewController : UIViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {

    func imagePicked(image: UIImage) {
        imagePicked = image
    }


    var imagePicked:UIImage! {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = imagePicked
        }
    }

    let button: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Select an image", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleImagePicker), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
        iv.layer.borderWidth = 2
        iv.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return iv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = "Get image via Delegate"
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(button)
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.button.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true

    }

    @objc func handleImagePicker() {
        let myPickerVC = myPickerViewController()
        myPickerVC.imagePickerDelegate = self

        self.present(myPickerVC, animated: true, completion: nil )
    }

}
```

You create a new project and paste the entire code it will works, I guess, like me.
Hope it helps

Comment: I want to use the imagePicker in multiple locations in the app for different reasons. Therefore the best would be to just pass the selectedImageFromPicker to what ever ViewController that is called from. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you be more precise please I am not sure to understand. Update your question if you can

Comment: I've now updated the original question. hope this helps

Comment: all the viewControllers that will use the picker have the same design ?

Comment: What do you mean by the same design? They look different and will have different code.. so I would say they are different, but they will use a picker in the same way...

Comment: as @dfd said, implementing your own delegate protocol may be the key. I'll update my answer with my approach. Even if his answer is right, I tried to subclass UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Apologies for giving the same answer. It's probably the best approach and both of us were working in that direction. I'm removing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 4.2**

Getting image from imagePicker changed like below code with Swift 4.2.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
        imagePickerDelegate.imagePicked(image: selectedImage)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```